# How to open QMenu without stealing mouse focus

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have custom delegate for `QListView` which can open `QMenu` as it's extension. I've managed to make it work, but at moment `QMenu` is open `QListView` doesn't have a focus anymore.

Is there a way for `QListView` and `QMenu` share mouse focus so it's possible to scroll through menu and list at the same time?